# Как заменить заглавные буквы на строчные и наоборот через charCodeAt()

Tags: javascript

Как большие буквы сделать меньше и наоборот в строке через charCodeAt()?

```js
let str = 'LoReM IsPuM';
let str1 = 'AaZz';
let a = str[0].charCodeAt(); // 76 
let a1 = str1[1].charCodeAt(); // 97 

for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.charCodeAt[i] < a || str.charCodeAt[i] > a1) {
    str.replace(/str/g, str[i].toLowerCase());
  } else {
    str1.replace(/str/g, str[i].toUpperCase());
  }
}

alert(str);
```

Comment: метод `replace` - не меняет исходную строку, поэтому если ты никуда не присваиваешь результат - он просто теряется.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'HelloWorld';
let newStr = '';

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  const cc = str.charCodeAt(i);
  newStr += String.fromCharCode(cc + (cc > 96 ? -32 : 32));
}

console.log(newStr);
```

P.S. Не брал во внимание символы не из алфавита.

Comment: спосибо большое!